# Use canvas's "strokeRect" function with "shadowBlur" property will fill the rect range

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas

I use the following code to draw a hollow rectangular.

```
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.shadowOffsetX = 1;
ctx.shadowOffsetY = 1;
// ctx.shadowBlur    = 1;
ctx.strokeStyle = '#f00'; 
ctx.lineWidth   = 1;
ctx.strokeRect(x, y, w,h);
```

It is fine. But when I set the ctx's shadowBlur property, the rectangular is filled. And it is fine in firefox.
[image]

Comment: You have too many tabs open :)

Comment: Can you place a reduction in jsbin.com?

Comment: I would like. But I do not know jsbin.com. I have to learn it first.

Comment: @coordinate use http://jsfiddle.net/, the purpose of using that is to show us a reduction of what your doing so we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have report a bug at google code. The solution is change linewidth from 1 to 1.1. And it works.

Get more information at:

[chromium Issue 121251](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=121251)

Answer (score 1):

You would need restore the context when you do another stroke.

```
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.save();
ctx.shadowOffsetX = 1;
ctx.shadowOffsetY = 1;
ctx.shadowBlur    = 1;
ctx.strokeStyle = '#f00'; 
ctx.restore();

ctx.lineWidth   = 1;
ctx.strokeRect(x, y, w,h);
```

Or just set `shadowBlur` to null after you finished the stroke you want blurred.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I want to blur the rect's border. If I set shadowBlur to null or 0, the rect is hollow, but the border is not blurred. This happens in the chrome and fine in firefox.

Comment: I have report a bug at google code. Then solution is change linewidth from 1 to 1.1. And it works.